# Making space in Lilypond music

Tags: music

I want to make some extra space between the main body of the music and the coda. I use \break to start the coda on a new line, but a wider gap would look better and help the eye move down to find it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.16/Documentation/notation/explicit-staff-and-system-positioning), you can use the following command after \break:

```
\overrideProperty #"Score.NonMusicalPaperColumn" #'line-break-system-details #'((Y-offset . 80))
```